# Create reactive filter in RShiny that returns only rows relevant to input

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, shiny, reactive

Please could you help me have a look at my code and tell me where I'm tripping up?

I'm trying to give a drop down input where users can select a category and then filter my data table by the chosen category to return a slimmed down version of my table with only a few columns. For context, all the columns are categorical variables.

```
``ui <- fluidPage(h1("SPIES Greece"), theme = shinytheme("darkly"),
            tabsetPanel(

            #ECOSYSTEM SERVICES
            tabPanel("Ecosystem Services", icon = icon("leaf", class = NULL, lib = "font-    awesome"),
                     selectInput("ecoservice.input", "Select Ecosystem Service:",
                                 c(unique(evidence.base$ecosystem.service))),
                     submitButton(text = "Apply Changes", icon = NULL, width = NULL),
                     dataTableOutput("ecoservice.filter")),
            ))

#server
server <- function(input, output, session)
 {
  #ecosystem service filter
  ecoservice.data <- reactive({
evidence.base %>%
  dplyr::filter(grepl(input$ecoservice.input, ecosystem.service))  %>%
  group_by(outcome, management.action)
  })

  #ecosystem service output
  output$ecoservice.filter <- renderDataTable(data_frame(ecoservice.data))
}

#app run
shinyApp(ui, server)`
```

`

I've done quite a few mini amendments and rerun the app over and over but can't seem to understand exactly where the issue lies, however I'll be the first to admit that reactive (and shiny in general) confuses me! Please let me know if you can help. TIA

I tried doing the filtering in a separate document completely outside of shiny to check that was working and then I tried changing from renderDataTable to renderTable (no difference). I got some odd errors like "object object" and "Input to asJSON(keep_vec_names=TRUE) is a named vector. In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead. See ?toJSON". Some of the time the titles of the table loaded into the app but the actual filter returned nothing at all (there were definitely entries in the data table with it on!)

Comment: `ecoservice.data` is a reactive. To access its content you have to use `ecoservice.data()`, e.g. `renderDataTable( ecoservice.data() )`. Additionally, instead of `grepl` you could use `%in%` to filter your data: `filter( ecosystem.service %in% input$ecoservice.input)`.

Comment: Thank you that is really helpful! It is now working thanks to you :)